# Determining Time Complexity of Merge K Sorted Arrays

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, merge

I wrote a Merge K Sorted Arrays. I found the best time Time Complexity for this to be O(n*k Logk) on other sites, where `k` is the number of Arrays and `n` is the number of elements in each array. 
I think mine is O(n*k).

Can anybody confirm this?? The code is below.

```
private static void MergeKSortedArrays()
{
    int[][] arr = { new int[] { 3, 5, 7 }, new int[] { 1, 2, 4 }, new int[] { 6, 8, 9 } };
    int k = 3, n = 3;

    int[] output = new int[n * k];
    int[] temp = new int[k];

    for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++)
    {
        temp = Merge(arr[i], arr[i + 1]);  // takes Linear time
        arr[i + 1] = temp;
    }

    foreach(int i in arr[k-1])
    {
        Console.Write(i + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

}

private static int[] Merge(int[] a, int[] b)
{
    int[] o = new int[a.Length + b.Length];
    int i = 0, j = 0, ind = 0;

    for (; i < a.Length && j < b.Length;)
    {
        if (a[i] <= b[j])
        {
            o[ind] = a[i];
            i++;
            ind++;
        }
        else
        {
            o[ind] = b[j];
            j++;
            ind++;
        }
    }

    if (i < a.Length)
    {
        for (; i < a.Length; i++, ind++)
        {
            o[ind] = a[i];
        }
    }
    else if (j < b.Length)
    {
        for (; j < b.Length; j++, ind++)
        {
            o[ind] = b[j];
        }
    }

    return o;
}
```

Comment: `Merge` takes linear time, yes .... but with regards to the sizes of the inputs. Are you sure both arrays are of size `n` ? Of could one of the be bigger (`O(nk)`) as arrays are being merged ?

Comment: If you want to get nearer to O(`nk`), you should process all k lists at once (instead of pairwise). This requires you to keep k pointers to the current positions in each of the k lists, and always take an element from the list with the smallest element. However, choosing the smallest element among k is O(`k`) - or O(`log k`) with a min-heap. That yields the overall O(`k n log k`) complexity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No.**

In the first iteration you merge an array of length n with an array of length n

In the second iteration you merge an array of length n with an array of length 2n

In the thrid iteration you merge an array of length n with an array of length 3n

...

This means the for loop in your Merge() method will run 2n + 3n + 4n... = `(k+1)*k/2 * n -1` times.

So your proposed algorithm is actually `O(n * k^2)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply... I appreciate it. Wouldn't the loop run like 2n + 3n+ 4n or what I mean is O( n+n) ,then O(2n +n) like that??

Comment: @ArmaanChugh agree!